# Load tables from excel sheets with both multilevel column data frames and single level column data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet with tables in multiple workbooks.

[image]

[image]

I want to load all the tables from excel workbooks to pandas dataframes using pandas.read_excel() function.

But the problem is few tables have single level columns and few tables have multilevel columns.

I wrote the following code to handle this issue. This code is working fine, but I want to know if there is any standard pythonic way of handling this issue.

```
xl = r"D:\\xl_tables.xlsx"

f = pd.ExcelFile(xl)

f.sheet_names = ["multilevel_column", "single_level_column" ]

dfl = []
for i in f.sheet_names:
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=i, header=[0,1])
        df.iloc[0,1]
        dfl.append(df)
    except:
        df = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=i)
        df.iloc[0,1]
        dfl.append(df)
```

Comment: Add a screenshot please.

Comment: Added - @Corralien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems to be good but avoid to catch all exceptions. I think you can probably replace `except` by `except ValueError`.
Also, use `ExcelFile` rather than reopen your file multiple times.

```
dfl = []
with pd.ExcelFile("sample.xlsx") as reader:
  for sheet_name in reader.book.sheetnames:
    df = reader.parse(sheet_name, header=None)
    if pd.isnull(df.iloc[1, 0]):
        idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.iloc[:2].values)
        i = 2
    else:
        idx = pd.Index(*df.iloc[:1].values)
        i = 1
    dfl.append(pd.DataFrame(df[i:].values, columns=idx))
```